# Select all row on excel table (not worksheet) w/ VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table connected to a DB, what I want to do is when the user click on a cell from this table : It select all the row of the table. Here's a copy of my code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If inTabRange(ActiveCell) Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tabRecherche").ListRows(ActiveCell.row).Range.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function inTabRange(cellRange As Range) As Boolean
    inRange = Not (Application.Intersect(cellRange, Range("Q14:AI700")) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

"tabRecherche" is the name of my table and it's range is from Q14 to AI700

My issue is that when I call the function "inTabRange", whether or not it returns True, the code goes in the Else part and call the MsgBox.

It may be an issue with how I'm using Application.Intersect : I copied this line from the Internet.

Hope you can help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will work with any table in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LObj As ListObject
    Set LObj = ActiveCell.ListObject       

    If LObj Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Hello"
    Else
     Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.Intersect(LObj.Range, ActiveCell.EntireRow).Select
     Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If       

End Sub
```

Comment: From a purely logical point of view I'd keep those `Application.EnableEvents` statements surrounding `Application.Intersect...`  within the `Else` condition block.  I'd also add that a check for table name would fully match OP's needs

Comment: Thank You @user3598756, I think like that too but maybe OP want to select anything else instead of the `msgbox`.

Comment: Yes the msgBox was just for the testing

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If inTabRange(Target) Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tabRecherche").Range.Rows.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function inTabRange(cellRange As Range) As Boolean
    inTabRange = Not Application.Intersect(cellRange, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tabRecherche").Range) Is Nothing
End Function
```

(This solution simply fixes your code. Fadi's solution is superior.)

Edit: replaced ActiveSheet.Rows(Target.Row).Select with ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tabRecherche").Range.Rows.Select - so now it select the whole table, not just the row. Oops.